# Change WebRequest's Method property (C#)

Tags: c#, methods, properties, ftp, invalidoperationexception

Is there a better way for changing the Method property of WebRequests after uploading a file than mine?

My way looks like this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://.../...txt");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// Then I write to the request stream with StreamWriter

// Try reading
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    // If I only change the Method property, the next line throws an InvalidOperationException

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), true);
```

Comment: You need to make a second request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects created by `WebRequest.Create` can be used only once, so you need to create new one to send another request.

```
var someLocation = "ftp://.../...txt";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(someLocation);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
// Then I write to the request stream with StreamWriter

// Create new request with the same parameters:
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(someLocation);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
using(StreamReader reader = 
   new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), true))...
```

Note that each request contains a other one-time objects like request stream and response stream (both are `NetworkStream` and don't support seek). If one would allow reuse of request created by `WebRequest.Create` it will require some resetting of all related object which essentially the same as creating new one but with downside of being implicit result of changing `Method` (or Url, or headers or pretty much any other property on the object). Design of .Net classes prefer explicit actions over implicit. You'll find other examples like disposed objects like `FileStream` can't be magically restored back to original state y changing file location property.

Comment: I knew that this way works but I didn't know why... Thanks a lot :)